# TYPO3 redirects regarding base / leading to 404 when all languages are configured with language slug as base

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

How can I configure redirects within the TYPO3 v9 redirect module regarding the base `/`  when all languages are configured with language slug as base `/de/`, `/en/`  and so on?

My Problem is a redirect with `source_path` like `/something` is resulting in a 404.

I checked with xdebug. The 404 happens because the processed `$route` does not have language information, which is set in `config.yaml` on key `languages:` but here not matching because of the defined base.

To make this more clear some examples:

- all existing pages are reachable like `http://typo3.demo.local:3000/de/example1/` `http://typo3.demo.local:3000/en/example1/` and so on
- plain base url `http://typo3.demo.local:3000/` redirects to default language `http://typo3.demo.local:3000/de/` by default behaviour
- within TYPO3 v9 redirect module a redirect should follow from `http://typo3.demo.local:3000/test1/` to `http://typo3.demo.local:3000/de/example1/` **but there is no redirect**, it shows the content from 404 page on `http://typo3.demo.local:3000/test1/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed for a while in https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87455#note-7

So switch to typo3 10 which has a feature switch or use a workaround like this I copied from the forge issue:

```
return [ 'frontend' => [ 'typo3/cms-redirects/redirecthandler' => [ 'disabled' => true, ], 'hotfix-redirecthandler' => [ 'target' => \TYPO3\CMS\Redirects\Http\Middleware\RedirectHandler::class, 'before' => [ 'typo3/cms-frontend/base-redirect-resolver', ], ], ], ];
```

In an extension at `Configuration/RequestMiddlewares.php`