# TYPO3 9.5 - Redirects with cms-redirects

Tags: regex, redirect, typo3

I am using TYPO3 v9.5.15 and would like to configure some automatics redirects.
I would like users accessing https://www.example.com/about-us/ to be redirected on a specific internal page.

Website has to configured languages (french and german). Here is the site configuration :

```
base: 'https://www.example.com'
baseVariants:
  -
    base: 'https://local.example.com'
    condition: 'getenv("HTTP_HOST") == "local.example.com"'
  -
    base: 'https://staging.domain.com'
    condition: 'getenv("HTTP_HOST") == "staging.example.com"'
errorHandling:
  -
    errorCode: '404'
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=157'
languages:
  -
    title: Français
    enabled: true
    base: /fr/
    typo3Language: fr
    locale: fr_CH
    iso-639-1: fr
    navigationTitle: FR
    hreflang: fr-CH
    direction: ltr
    flag: fr
    languageId: '0'
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_CH
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: DE
    hreflang: de-CH
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: de
    languageId: '1'
rootPageId: 84
routes: {  }
```

And here is the configured redirection :

[image: Configured redirection image]

Redirection works only with https://www.example.com/fr/about-us/ or https://www.example.com/de/about-us/ and not without the language segment. Without language segment, I am getting 404 error page.

When debugging *\TYPO3\CMS\Redirects\Service\RedirectService->matchRedirect()*, my regex is compared with current URI path. Instead of */about-us/*, the path is */fr/page-not-found*, which means and redirection already occurred. And the matching fail as my regex is :

```
#^(.*)/about-us/$#
```

Does anyone have a solution with this ?
Thanks in advance for your help.
Regards
Julien

Comment: I can't reproduce this with latest TYPO3. Using a standard TYPO3 instance with introduction package and configuring /en for default language, then add redirect with regex: `#^(.*)/about-us$#`.  Maybe problem was solved or is_regex checkbox not activated? If problem still exists, maybe submit an issue?

Comment: In any case, better to use more specific redirects as suggested in answer, e.g. `#^(fr|de|)/about-us$#`

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59746834/typo3-redirects-regarding-base-leading-to-404-when-all-languages-are-configure Might be a problem in v9 which no longer occurs.

Comment: Related issue: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87455

Answer (score 0):

The reason you getting a 404 is, that your regular expression only matches pages with something filled at the start, ending in `/about-us/` - in your case the language segment or any path folder.

So to say, you did not configured a redirect for **"Without language segment"**.

One way, adding a second redirect with:

```
#^/about-us/$#
```

as regular expression, and the using the same settings for the other settings, it should do what you want.

Anyway, would omit the (.*) placeholder, because it matches to much. Being more descriptive saves headcache and uncontrolled matchings.

Otherwise, you have to create a regular expression, which matches both cases, with and without language segment:

```
#^/([a-z0-9-]+)(/|)about-us/$#
```

or more open:

```
#^/(.*)(/|)about-us/$#
```

Or, if you have a path structure, would be better to limit only to the known language segments:

```
#^/(en/|fr/|de/|)about-us/$#
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

I tried with your differents propositions but unfortunately it does not work.
The probleme is when https://www.example.com/about-us/ is called, TYPO3 transform the URL to https://www.example.com/fr/page-not-found/ before the redirection service.
And then, the path tested with the regular expression is "/fr/page-not-found/" instead of "/about-us/" or "/fr/about-us/".

I hope I am clear enough ;-)

Comment: normaly the redirect service is run before doing an 404. There must be something that changed that.
I have tested the above reges on a v9 page, with not existing pages .. and they where redirect first.

Eventuelly try it without the ending "/" in the regexp. or with (/|)$# and the end of the regexp instead of /$#

Otherwise something is influencing your system before hand. Have you checkt the middlewers or any extensions ? But as i sed, redirect should normally happen before any page detection and 404 handling internal ...

Comment: I tried changing the end of the regular expression without success.
I am going to check why the 404 error is triggered before redirect service.
Thank you very much for helping. I will give feedback as soon as I found something.

Comment: @JulienFourel Did you find a proper solution for that? I am currently facing this issue aswell on TYPO3 10. I wanted to redirect a path like "/files/a/b/c.pdf" to "/fileadmin/d/e/f.pdf". But every redirect which has no language parameter in the beginning like "/de/..." will be redirected to 404.

Comment: @BastianW Unfortunately I did not find any solution for this.